# how to write integer to array passed with INVOKE?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I can't come to grips with this simple problem, which involves writing integers to an array. As you can see in the code below, I pass addresses to a procedure and attempt to write to the array. I tried accessing the array all different kinds of ways, but it appears accessing address locations in a procedure doesn't work the same as inside MAIN. I can't imagine why `freqTable` would be inaccessible in function `get_freq`. Please enlighten me.

```
.data
target BYTE "aaaa",0
freqTable DWORD 256 DUP(0)

.code
get_freq PROC,table PTR DWORD
mov table[0],'b'  <---  writing 'b' to wrong address
ret 
get_freq endp

main PROC
INVOKE get_freq,ADDR freqTable
exit 
main ENDP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the expression `mov table[0],'b'` you refer to the address of `table` instead of the value of `table`=`ADDR freqTable` as passed as parameter. So you would write to the stack which contains the LOCAL variable `table` and not to the DATA segment where the value of table points to (=`freqTable`).

So, to make this work, you'd have to use the value of `table` as an address:

```
get_freq PROC table: PTR DWORD
  mov eax, table            <--- get value of table=ADDR freqTable to EAX
  mov DWORD PTR [eax], 'b'  <--- writing 'b' to address with value EAX
  ret 
get_freq endp
```

If you want to add an index to the address, you can use

```
mov DWORD PTR [eax+ecx], 'b'
```

for that with `ECX` as an index register, for example. In the case of your case `ECX` should be `0`.

> it appears accessing address locations in a procedure doesn't work the same as inside MAIN.

Yes. There is a difference between using a direct address (global variable) and an address passed as parameter (like in a PROC). The example above attempts to illustrate that.

Global variables can always be accessed by using the `OFFSET` directive like

```
mov eax, offset freqTable
```

If you add another indirection like using a parameter passed to a procedure, you'd have to take that into account like

```
push offset freqTable       <!-- store address on stack
call get_freq               <!-- call procedure with variable on stack
...                         
mov eax, variableName       <!-- get address from stack
mov DWORD PTR [eax], 'b'    <!-- use it
```

So the second possibility of using a parameter opens up a way to pass run-time-values to a procedure which is impossible using the compile-time-values offered by the `OFFSET` way.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. Why don't we need to store the address in a register in the main procedure? The extra step of storing the address in the get_freq procedure seems unnecessary

Comment: This is related to a restriction of the IA32 _Instruction Set Architecture_. It simply doesn't offer this possibility.